# Fibration in topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Can anybody give some examples of geometrical explanation of the concept fibration in topology?  I found some examples of this concept but they are mere abstract and therefore I'm unable to grasp the idea.

Comment: Consider a fiber bundle.

Comment: Look up path space fibrations and the associated LES.

Comment: any covering projection map is fibration here you have plenty of fibration examples, and take the following fibration which aren't covering projection for any topological X space take X*Q (Q is the set of rational numbers here and this is a fibration in general for any Q)and as a map take first projection.

Comment: Further to @anomaly's comment, as a 'fiber bundle' is a kind of fibration, Wikipedia's [examples of fiber bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle#Examples) might be of help to you.